# Instantiate a single connection to db with trait mixin in Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, slick, mixins, traits, slick-3.0

I have a trait which defines a db connection:

```
trait Db {
  val db: Database = Database.forConfig("twitter-indexing-db")
}
```

Then I extend that in another trait where I make use of `Db` like so:

```
trait TwitterIndexingRepository {
  self: Db =>
  ...
}
```

Finally I instantiate an object with the desired functionality:

```
object PostgresTwitterIndexingRepository extends TwitterIndexingRepository with Db
```

*If I have multiple mixins will I have multiple connections/connection pools open to the given db?*

This seems kind of bad as opposed to e.g. Spring DI where you'd get one connection and inject that everywhere you need it.

Comment: Short answer is yes, use an object or a class which you can inject into your postgres persistence class.

Comment: I'd solve that by having an `implicit` that contains all of your global instances like DB connection, logger etc.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're trying to use the [cake pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/t_rapw/cake-pattern-in-scala-self-type-annotations-explicitly-typed-self-references-explained).

If that's what you'd like to use, the `Db` trait should use a `def`, and `PostgresTwitterIndexingRepository` should override with a `val`:

```
trait Db {
  def db: Database
}

object PostgresTwitterIndexingRepository
    extends TwitterIndexingRepository with Db {
  override val db = Database.forConfig("twitter-indexing-db")
}
```

This will only create one database instance, as you wanted. As the commenters mention, you could also use other methods to ensure only one instance is created - constructor parameters, implicit constructor parameters, global singletons, etc.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the cake pattern since it allows me to do DI without frameworks and testing stuff is a breeze. 
Can you give an explanation of why doing what you suggest in the anser will ensure I get a single instance?
Also when you say constructor parameters I presume you imply using class instead of a trait?
I try to avoid implicit as much as possible.

Comment: The short answer is: Because you're forced to only use one instance of the database, provided by the outer class. Technically, in your example, Scala should figure out that all of the traits extend `Db`, and only put it in one location in the class hierarchy for `PostgresTwitterIndexingRepository`. However, if you extend the trait in another concrete class, you'll get a new instance.